# Swift LocationManager Horizontal Accuracy

Tags: ios, swift, locationmanager

Is it possible to get location manager to register changes in location of a foot or less? I'd like to tap a button and register one location and move a short distance (foot or less) and tap another button to register that location. I'm trying now with the 13 decimal places provided but I see no difference. When I check the  horizontal accuracy I'm only getting 65 meters. I'm indoors. New to this.

Comment: "When I check the horizontal accuracy I'm only getting 65 meters" Well, there's your answer.

Comment: So how do I get a more precise reading/accuracy? Is it possible? I'm already set to "kCLLocationAccuracyBest".

Comment: What you get is what you get. Even outdoors I never get much better than 10m. But maybe your code for getting one location is faulty. You must allow several readings to come in; the equipment takes time to warm up.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that but I was trying to see if there was anything else I could do that I hadn't seen/thought of. Much appreciated.

Comment: Show your code, though. It may be that you're just doing this wrong.